# My code receives the message from the queue multiple time, I want to receive it only one time. How can I do it?

Tags: queue, jms, websphere, message-queue

I am new, so my question is relatively easy, I guess.

I am using Websphere Application Server platform and default JMS provider to send and receive message from queue. This is how my app looks like:

[image]

Saytime is my main servlet which reroute my code to a .jsp file. The "Produce" button sends the app following code and generate the message written in box:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String queueName = "jms/helloqueue";
    Context jndiContext = null;
    QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFcatory = null;
    QueueConnection queueConnection = null;
    QueueSession queueSession = null;
    QueueSender queueSender = null;
    Queue queue = null;
    TextMessage textMessage = null;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // To information the that you may use Unicode characters
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String txt = request.getParameter("text");
   
    try {
        Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
        initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2810");
        jndiContext = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        queueConnectionFcatory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/helloqcf");
        queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup(queueName);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        queueConnection = queueConnectionFcatory.createQueueConnection();
        queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
        textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage();
        
        textMessage.setText(txt);
        queueSender.send(textMessage);
        
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("JMS Exception occured: "+ e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(queueConnection != null){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                queueConnection.close();
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saytime");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

The "Receive" button sends my app to following servlet code and receives the message from queue:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String queueName = "jms/helloqueue";
    Context jndiContext = null;
    QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionfactory = null;
    QueueConnection queueConnection = null;
    QueueSession queueSession = null;
    QueueReceiver queueReceiver = null;
    Queue queue = null;
    String text = null;

    try {
        Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
        initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://localhost:2810");
        jndiContext = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("JNDI exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        queueConnectionfactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/helloqcf");
        queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup(queueName);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        queueConnection = queueConnectionfactory.createQueueConnection();
        queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
        //queueReceiver.setMessageListener(listener);
        queueConnection.start();
        text = queueReceiver.receive().toString();
        
    } catch(JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured: "+ e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (queueConnection != null) {
            try {
                queueConnection.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    if(text != null) {
        request.setAttribute("message", text.toString());
    }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saytime");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

After that I print the message with this little code in my .jsp file:

```java
<%
String getValues = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
%>
<%
if (getValues != null) {
    out.println("<p>" + getValues + "</p>");
} else {
    out.println("<p> There is no message </p>");
}
%>
```

The problem is this: I am able to take my produced message, but the button continues to receive the message till the count on JMSXDeliveryCount hit 5. Mostly JMSXDeliveryCount start with 1 and total I can receive the message 5 times. I want to receive it only once and then message to disappear.

Additionally, I want to know how I can print only my message. I print with additional details like you see in the picture. If it's possible, I don't want that.

I tried to limit redelivery number, but I am unable to come up with right code I guess. Also, I tried to use different acknowledgement mode but, it did not work either.

I got really confused with it, some help would be perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're creating the consumer's session as **transacted**. See this line:

```java
queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

The acknowledgement mode will be ignored since the session is transacted (i.e. you're passing `true` in the first parameter). This is noted in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession-boolean-int-) which states:

> If `transacted` is set to `true` then the session will use a local transaction which may subsequently be committed or rolled back by calling the session's `commit` or `rollback` methods. The argument `acknowledgeMode` is ignored.

Therefore, you should either acknowledge the message and commit the session manually, e.g.:

```java
Message message = queueReceiver.receive();
text = message.toString();
message.acknowledge();
queueSession.commit();
```

Or you should use a non-transacted session and allow the message to be auto-acknowledged according to the acknowledgement mode, e.g.:

```java
queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Typically transacted sessions are only used when multiple operations (i.e. send and receive) need to be combined together atomically. Since you're only consuming a single message here I would recommend you just use a non-transacted session.

Also, you will eventually want to cache the `javax.jms.Connection` or perhaps use a connection pool rather than creating a connection, session, & producer/consumer for *every* message. This is an anti-pattern and should be avoided whenever possible.